# Access field from another field in the same class?

Tags: c#

I'm working on this piece of code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public AnotherClass aClass;
    public static DifferentClass dClass = new DifferentClass();
}
```

How is it possible to use `aClass` inside `DifferentClass` (in `someMethod`for example) ?

```
public class DifferentClass {
    public someMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can´t, as `DifferentClas` knows nothing about `AnotherClass`, unless you provide it, e.g. via construcotr-argument.

Comment: If `DifferentClass` has a property `AnotherClass` named `bClass`, you can use `bClass` in `someMethod()`. It is quite hard to understand your problem, please add some tests cases and a [MCVE].

Comment: You should do a bit of reading on [static keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) because from a static element you cannot access a non-static element without generating an instance of it. Maybe you wanted to use inheritance but you got confused?

Answer (score 0):

Provide an instance of Your `AnotherClass` to `DifferenctClass` as constructor's parameter.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static AnotherClass aClass = new AnotherClass(); // Create instance
    public static DifferentClass dClass = new DifferentClass(aClass);
}

public class DifferentClass
{

    private readonly AnotherClass _aClass;

    public DifferentClass(AnotherClass aClass)
    {
        _aClass = aClass;
    }

    public someMethod() {
        // Use _aClass here
    }
}
```